# Kotlin не видит R.layout

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

При добавлении плагина `kotlin-android-extensions` появляется ошибка Unresolved reference R, т.е. перестает видеть лэйаут. Как это можно исправить? Clean project не помог.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При использовании Kotlin Android Extensions доступ к виджетам осуществляется через импорт виджетов, а не обращение к классу ресурсов R.

Например, обращение ко всем виджетам разметки с именем `activity_main.xml`:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.* // импорт ссылок на виджеты

class MyActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textView1.setText("Hello, world!") // обращение к виджету с ID textView1
    }
}
```

то есть, импортировав разметку в проект, в дальнейшем мы просто обращаемся к виджетам на ней по их ID, указанным в разметке (через атрибут `android:id`), не требуется использовать метод `findViewById()` для доступа к виджетам.

Официальная [документация](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html)

Comment: аааа точно вспомнил

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема с R или R.layout(.menu,.id) повторяется, и при этом R импортирована, то стоит заребилдить проект. Особенно это касается kotlin. Во время билда все ссылки будут снова словлены IDE и проблема решится сама собой.
Если появяется проблема с элементами под R.xxx.???, то стоит удостовериться, что в id элеметов или названия файлов не имею синтаксических ошибок и установлены. К тому же некоторые названия могут некотироваться.